# Ordering by a APP_USER in oracle apex

Tags: oracle

Below query gets results as listed in results 1 
I would like it to display as result set 2 IE the logged in user shows first

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
              CLIENT_BRANCH BRANCH,
       ACCOUNT_NO,
       CLIENT_SPECIALIST
  FROM CL$CLIENTS
 WHERE COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID
```

Current results

```
Client_id   Branch                       Account_no CLIENT_SPECIALIST
1000001034  Training Force Isando        FTEC01       LAUREN
1000001035  Training Force Isando        EZUL01       Jack
1000001798  Training Force Isando        ISMEP02      SAMUEL
1000002064  Training Force Parktown      TTEL01       LAUREN
1000002191  Phalaborwa                   FOSK01       WICKUS
1000002314  Training Force Nelspruit     RUD01        ERICK
1000002318  Training Force Phalaborwa    SUS08        ZANELE
```

Query:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
                  CLIENT_BRANCH BRANCH,
           ACCOUNT_NO,
           CLIENT_SPECIALIST
      FROM CL$CLIENTS
     WHERE COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID
     ORDER by :APP_USER (First)
```

Required Results

```
Client_id   Branch                       Account_no CLIENT_SPECIALIST
1000001034  Training Force Isando        FTEC01       LAUREN
1000002064  Training Force Parktown      TTEL01       LAUREN
1000002191  Phalaborwa                   FOSK01       WICKUS
1000002314  Training Force Nelspruit     RUD01        ERICK
1000002318  Training Force Phalaborwa    SUS08        ZANELE
1000001035  Training Force Isando        EZUL01       Jack
1000001798  Training Force Isando        ISMEP02      SAMUEL
```

Comment: Is the CLIENT_SPECIALIST "LAUREN" the App User?

Comment: Yes , but requirement could be Jack or Samuel that login , Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the App user is present in Client_specialist column, you can use a `CASE` in the order by clause to produce custom ordering:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
    CLIENT_BRANCH BRANCH,
    ACCOUNT_NO,
    CLIENT_SPECIALIST
FROM CL$CLIENTS
WHERE COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID
order by case when CLIENT_SPECIALIST = :APP_USER then 0 else 1 end;
```